# Show that $e^n>\frac{(n+1)^n}{n!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, exponential-function

My brother give me a question that was

To show that

$$e^n>\frac{(n+1)^n}{n!}$$ where $n\in \mathbb Z^+$

Please help me!!!

Comment: $n \in \Bbb Z$? not in $\Bbb N$? Do you what is $n!$ for $n<0$?

Comment: How about induction?